# Unity dll works in the editor but fails to load in standalone

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the TensorFlow.net library for loading some machine learning models. Everything works fine in the editor. However, when I am building the app (Windows standalone app) the dll is not loaded and therefore callbacks to the TensorFlow models cannot be made. The strangest thing is that the dll works fine and is loaded when I build the player as a development build with script debugging enabled. I tried moving the dll next to the .exe on the root folder but the problem persisted.

Any ideas on how to approach the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this so I am posting the answer in case someone might find this helpful in the future.

The problem was that I have added all the managed and native DLLs inside the Unity project manually by downloading the dll from visual studio through nugget, compiling, and then copying the file inside the assets/Plugins folder. That probably created some dependencies that they were working inside the editor but the dll was unable to find the corresponding package when building the app.

The solution came by using nuget2Unity that automatically downloads NuGet packages and translates them to unity packages. Using this tool I was able to make it work both in the editor and standalone player. In case you follow this solution and you receive errors such as "unloading broken assembly", "could not load signature", just move all the managed dlls to the same Plugins folder under assets and the error will go away.

I hope this answer may come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem - "**Couldn't Load the signature**" and I have followed your strategy.
Though I am unable to find the nuget2Unity package, I found this package on github - https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity/releases/tag/v2.0.1

This works well for me.

I also found that the .Net Core packages doesn't work with Unity's Mono, and there are no news about it till now.